# function takes exactly 2 argument 3 (given) python cx_orcale Insert Error

Tags: python, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

I am having Oracle Database and I am trying to insert a dataframe into an existing table but getting error of extra arguments. my connection to database is successful.

**My Dataframe**

```
    TMIDS MEM_ID 
1    8    UY2554
2    8    UY2573
3    8    UY2576
```

**My code:**

**Note: the connection coding part is skipped as it is working and is not required here**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
print("connection successful")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO UCIDBA.dummy_table (TMIDS,MEM_ID) values(?,?)",row.TMIDS, row.MEM_ID)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
print("inserted in table")
```

I am getting below error

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO UCIDBA.dummy_table (TMIDS,MEM_ID) values(?,?)",row.TMIDS, row.MEM_ID)

TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not use the `?` character to define parameters. They must be either numbered (`:1`) or named (`:name`). So your code should look like this:

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO UCIDBA.dummy_table (TMIDS,MEM_ID)
            values(:1, :2)""",
            [row.TMIDS, row.MEM_ID])
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
print("inserted in table")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the values as a tuple.
So, change your code to:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO UCIDBA.dummy_table (TMIDS,MEM_ID) values(?,?)",(row.TMIDS, row.MEM_ID))
```

Comment: getting below error when changing code as  suggested above 'cursor.execute("INSERT INTO UCIDBA.dummy_table (TMIDS,MEM_ID) values(?,?)",(row.TMIDS, row.MEM_ID))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number'

Answer (score 0):

Is execute a method of the cursor class?
If so, in it's definition, is the first argument self?

Pythons will send it implicitly but the function has to accept it explicitly.

It sounds like what is happening is that you are sending self, row.TMIDS, row.MEM_ID to a function that only expects row.TMIDS, row.MEM_ID